# How do I check that a minimum Ruby version is present at runtime?

Tags: ruby

I have an optional bit of code that requires Ruby >= 2.1.0. I would like to test at runtime if this requirement is met. What's the right way to do it?

I looked at the [Rails codebase](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/32f7491808d2c4e097ed7b3ee875e4d1cea8c442/railties/lib/rails/ruby_version_check.rb) and they use a simple string comparison like this:

```
RUBY_VERSION >= "2.1.0"
```

But isn't a string comparison of version numbers prone to error? Won't this return the wrong result if some future Ruby version is, say, "10.0.0"?

Comment: Why exactly does it require 2.1? Usually it's better to test for features (e.g. with the various `*defined?` methods) instead of versions.

Comment: You can also use `Gem::Version.new(RUBY_VERSION) >= Gem::Version.new('2.1.0')` since `rubygems` is required by default.

Comment: @cremno I am using refinements, which were not finalized until 2.1.

Comment: Well, rubinius also claims to be 2.1 but it doesn't have refinements. `Module.private_method_defined?(:using)` should work to detect 2.1 refinements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good notice, it seems you have found possible bug, either drop a note to [rails issue tracker](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues) or patch it by yourself and make a pull request.

There is small and simple [Versionomy](https://github.com/dazuma/versionomy) gem to compare versions correctly.

Comment: Indeed, this is a bug. It is such a common bug that for this reason alone, the version numbering scheme was changed and Ruby 1.10.0 was released as Ruby 1.9.1.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Is this mascot bug or something, why haven't they fixed this yet?

Comment: It's a bug in the heads of developers, you can't fix that. For every developer like Matt, who realizes that simple string comparison is wrong, there are 100 more who don't. The decision was between releasing Ruby 1.10 and "breaking" thousands of scripts (even though technically it's the scripts that are broken) or changing the version numbering scheme and releasing Ruby 1.9.1. It's similar to why Microsoft released Windows 7 with a version number of 6.1: Yes, all the apps which check for major number == 6 are wrong, but try to explain that to the end users, all *they* see is "Windows 7 broke …

Comment: … my app", they don't care that it's the app developer's fault, all they notice is it worked on Vista and doesn't on 7.